# Top Link Nav Bar

Tags: 2010, top-link-bar

I have configured a Top Link bar on my SharePoint 2010 site. It looks fine for my pages. But as I navigate to application pages the navigation levels split up e.g   MainHeading/Heading1/Leaf Nodes. This is my menu structure and when I open any application page it splits up in two Main heading and other is Heading1/Leaf Nodes.

I am not able to find out whats the reason behind this. As it looks fine on custom pages.

Please suggest.

This is how the menu looks on custom page

[image]

This is how top link bar looks on application pages.

[image]

Regards
VB

Comment: Could it be possible for you to share screenshots of the same?

Comment: Screen shots are shared.

Comment: Are you using different masterpage for site and system ?

Comment: No both are the same.

Comment: have a look in IE9 F12 developer tool (or Firebug in Firefox) the order of the CSS being used. Your application pages may be cancelling out the CSS you intended to use.